# How to mock services that uses strings in constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have my service, it is a simple injectable

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject('Container') container: string) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

And I am mocking it

```
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
        }),
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MyService,
          useValue: {
            find: (id: string) => 'test'
          }
        },
        {
          provide: 'Container',
          useValue: 'AnyValue'
        },
      ],
    }).compile();
    await module.init();
```

But it looks like isn't getting mocked, the service is making networking connections.

How can I property mock it?

Comment: What does this string have to do with making network connections?

Comment: Not the string, an internal database instance.

Comment: There's not enough information here to understand what you're meaning